# What is the start point of a Transaction in Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: transactions, wallets, nodes

As I learned so far, every node in network, has the address of other nodes and they can communicate with each other regarding mining new blocks, but what about the Wallets?

What will happen exactly when I send a transaction from my wallet?

Is there a centralized end-point which receive the transaction request from wallets and broadcast it to the network?

Is there any special node responsible for receiving transactions from wallets?

Does every wallet ( the company I mean ) has it's own nodes running?

And also the start point of the cycle of a new Node is unclear to me, What will happen when a new Node wants to join the network, what is the exact start point?

I know that the address of nodes are available globally for example here :
https://ethernodes.org/nodes

But I want to know exactly how a new Node is starting joining the network, is it sending a request to `https://ethernodes.org/XXXX` to register itself?!

Answer (score 0):

Every node in the ethereum network contain all the wallet information of the users present in the chain. When you do any transaction, It is broadcasted to all the nodes and they check by themselves if the transaction is valid or not, If more than 51% of the nodes agree, the transaction is sent to be mined and further be added to the blockchain.

No there is no special wallet or company present which receive the transactions. However a wallet should be connected to a node so that it could get the details of wallet. A wallet is independent to be connected to any node. There is no fixed thing that wallet has to be connected to a specific node or something.

It you want to run a new node, you have to download the whole blockchain data to your system. When the whole data is downloaded, then your machine is ready to include now transactions. There is nothing like a start point